# 400*1 cells in original data, 64*64 matrix in each cell, how to stretch the data into column vectors and form a 4096*400 matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to python and now I have a problem with my assignment.
There is a original dataset. In this dataset, there are 400 cells. In each cell, there is a 64*64 matrix.

```
    array([[ array([[ 75,  89, 101, ...,  90,  80,  74],
   [ 83,  98, 106, ...,  90,  82,  76],
   [ 83, 101, 109, ...,  92,  82,  72],
   ..., 
   [ 52,  50,  54, ...,  37,  40,  42],
   [ 49,  51,  51, ...,  36,  39,  40],
   [ 49,  50,  49, ...,  37,  39,  38]], dtype=uint8),

    array([[110, 114, 124, ...,  46,  45,  45],
   [108, 117, 126, ...,  52,  51,  51],
   [120, 125, 129, ...,  49,  50,  50],
   ..., 
   [187, 189, 192, ...,  35,  35,  35],
   [187, 188, 191, ...,  33,  33,  33],
   [185, 191, 189, ...,  37,  37,  37]], dtype=uint8),

    array([[ 77,  97, 119, ...,  97,  86,  75],
   [ 75,  96, 116, ...,  98,  91,  73],
   [ 65,  84, 110, ...,  96,  90,  75],
   ..., 
   [ 32,  24,  20, ...,  33,  36,  37],
   [ 28,  23,  19, ...,  35,  35,  38],
   [ 27,  22,  19, ...,  34,  36,  37]], dtype=uint8),
```

(400 of them)
I want to stretch the data into column vectors and form one matrix. In the new matrix, each column vector is consisted of the 64*64=4096 data in one cell of original data. And thus I can get a 4096*400 matrix.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question would be to reshape your array and then transpose it:

```
In [28]: a = np.arange(3*4*2).reshape(3,1,4,2)

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         [ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7]]],


       [[[ 8,  9],
         [10, 11],
         [12, 13],
         [14, 15]]],


       [[[16, 17],
         [18, 19],
         [20, 21],
         [22, 23]]]])

In [30]: a.reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[-2]*a.shape[-1]).T
Out[30]: 
array([[ 0,  8, 16],
       [ 1,  9, 17],
       [ 2, 10, 18],
       [ 3, 11, 19],
       [ 4, 12, 20],
       [ 5, 13, 21],
       [ 6, 14, 22],
       [ 7, 15, 23]])
```

As David pointed out in the comments, if you wanted to unroll the 64x64 matrices column-wise, use the *Fortran* ordering in `reshape`:

```
In [31]: a.reshape((a.shape[0], a.shape[-2]*a.shape[-1]), order='F').T
Out[31]: 
array([[ 0,  8, 16],
       [ 2, 10, 18],
       [ 4, 12, 20],
       [ 6, 14, 22],
       [ 1,  9, 17],
       [ 3, 11, 19],
       [ 5, 13, 21],
       [ 7, 15, 23]])
```

However, how you got your data to be printed in that form with `array([[ array([[` is unusual and it's not something I can immediately come up with *how* you did that. You might want to consider changing the way you generated that dataset: if the number of 64x64 "matrices" is known upfront, you could preallocate an array (`np.rempty(400, 64, 64)`) and then fill it. Otherwise, an ordinary Python list would suffice, to which you could append each new 64x64 matrix and at the end convert the list of arrays to a full numpy array (`np.array(list_of_matrices)`).

Comment: This also assumes that he wants to stretch them row-wise and not column-wise.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for the OP - it looks like he has a bunch of `np.uint8` arrays *nested inside* an `np.object` array. The dimensions of the outer array will only be `(400,)`, so the reshape will throw an exception.

Comment: @ali_m, indeed it won't work for the OP with the dataset he has in its current form. Which is why you and me both recommend he changes his array into a homogeneous form from the start. Thanks for showing me how such an array could be constructed. +1

Comment: thanks. I'm doing PCA and LDA on face recognition. The dataset is given by the professor and my question is the first step of my assignment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TianyingZhao, I'm not sure if I understood you well. I hope you're not giving up, as the solution is simply a combination of ali_m's answer and mine: first create a homogeneous array of dtype=np.uint8, then perform the reshape and transpose operations.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, how did you end up with *that*?

I can think of no good reason for nesting numeric arrays within an `np.object` array. You would have a much easier time if you were starting out with a `(400, 64, 64)` homogeneous array of dtype `np.uint8`, but that's a separate issue for you to think about.

I had to think for a minute how to even construct an array like yours. Here's a toy example - a `(3,)` `np.object` array containing `(2, 2)` `np.uint8` arrays:

```
arr = np.empty(3, dtype=np.object)
for ii in xrange(3):
    arr[ii] = np.arange(4, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2, 2)
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
print(repr(arr))
# array([array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]], dtype=uint8),
#        array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]], dtype=uint8),
#        array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]], dtype=uint8)], dtype=object)
```

*Eeew.* Let's say that we wanted to reshape this into a `(3, 4)` array. It's not possible to do this directly because the size of the outer `np.object` array 'container' is still only `(3,)`:

```
print(arr.shape)
# (3,)
arr.reshape(3, 4)
# ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

To turn that into something sensible we'll first stack the subarrays in the first dimension in order to make a homogeneous array of dtype `np.uint8`:

```
arr = np.vstack(subarr[None, ...] for subarr in arr)
print(repr(arr))
# array([[[0, 1],
#         [2, 3]],

#        [[0, 1],
#         [2, 3]],

#        [[0, 1],
#         [2, 3]]], dtype=uint8)
```

The `None` index is used here to insert a new (first) dimension that we stack the arrays over.

Now that we have a `(3, 2, 2)` *homogeneous* array, we can just flatten out the last two dimensions to make a `(3, 4)` array. A trick for this is to use the `.reshape()` method with a `-1` for the size of the last dimension, meaning that its size will be determined automatically based on the total number of elements in the array:

```
arr = arr.reshape(3, -1)
print(repr(arr))
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```